# How to find values such that the curves $y=\frac{a}{x-1}$ and $y=x^2-2x+1$ intersect at right angles?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:
Find all values of $a$ such that the curves $y = \frac{a}{x-1}$ and $y = x^2-2x+1$ intersect at right angles.

My attempt:
First, I set the two curves equal to each other:
$ \frac{a}{x-1} = x^2 - 2x + 1 $
$ \frac{a}{x-1} = (x-1)^2 $
$ \frac{a}{x-1}(x-1) = (x-1)^2(x-1) $
$ a = (x-1)^3 $
$ \sqrt[3] a = x-1 $
$ \sqrt[3] a + 1 = x $

​
I found the derivative of the first curve:
$ y = \frac{a}{x-1} $
$ y = a(x-1)^{-1} $
$ y' = -a(x-1)^{-2} $
$ y' = \frac{-a}{(x-1)^{2}} $

Then I found the derivative of the second curve:
$ y = x^2 - 2x + 1 $
$ y' = 2x - 2 $

Next, I multiplied them together and set them equal to -1:
$ \frac{-a}{(x-1)^{2}} ⋅ 2x - 2 = -1 $

$ \frac{-2ax + 2a}{(x-1)^2} = -1 $

$ \frac{-2a(x-1)}{(x-1)^2} = -1 $

$ \frac{-2a}{x-1} = -1 $

$ \frac{-2a}{x-1} ⋅ (x-1) = -1(x-1) $

$ -2a = -x+1 $

$ a = \frac{-x+1}{-2} $

Now I am unsure how to finish the problem. Do I substitute what I found for $x$ into $ a = \frac{-x+1}{-2} $?
But my problem shows that there are two possible answers for $a$ so I am confused.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If they intercept at right angles then the product of their slopes $m_1\cdot m_2=-1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $\dfrac{a}{x-1} = x^2- 2x+1 \implies a = (x-1)^3 = \dfrac{x-1}{2}$. Can you solve for $x$ and then $a$?

Comment: @Nguyen Check the values of $a$ and put them into the original equation to see if they are perpendicular. Some cases might not work in your original expression.

Comment: @DeepSea@Toby Mak - Thank you guys for your help! I kept reworking it, and I was able to figure it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Then,

$$\displaystyle a=\frac{X-1}2
a=(x-1)^3((\text{eq}
\frac{x-1}2=\frac{(x-1)^3}2
=\frac{(x-2)^2}2
2x^2-4x+2=1$$

So,

$$X=\frac{2+\sqrt 2}2, \frac{2-\sqrt 2}2$$
Put $x$ in eq $1$:

$$a= 2^{-\frac32}= \sqrt \frac 42$$

Comment: Please check the MathJax I have edited for you. Please correct my edits and read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).